# gRPC-Core Compile Errors - Apple Mach-O Linker Error after Swift 4/Xcode 9 Update

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, swift4, xcode9

After updating to Xcode 9.1 from 8.3.3 a project I am working on has multiple errors stemming from gRPC-Core bundled with Firebase. The errors make no sense whatsoever (to me at least) and I have tried all the usual fixes (removing pods, reinstalled, pod update, clean, build, delete derived data, etc). Cocoapods version is 1.3.1

[image: gRPC errors]

Pods being used in the project (everything working fine before update, no other errors from other pods).

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Firestore', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'UITextField+Shake', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'SJFluidSegmentedControl', :git => 'https://github.com/adornoventura/SJFluidSegmentedControl.git'
  pod 'GoogleBooksApiClient'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'BarcodeScanner'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'Stripe'
  pod 'Lightbox'
  pod 'SwipeCellKit'
```

Edit: To those with the same problem, this issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/423 and it stems from the Firestore pod.

Comment: Encountered exact issue xcode 9.0. occurred after reinstalling cocoapods due to High Sierra issues with existing cocoapods directory and updating my firebase podfile to include cloud firestore.

Comment: @cod_A Just found this issue is being tracked on the Firebase Github here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/423

Answer (score 2):

gRPC Team fixed this issue with the release of pod version 1.7.1. To anyone with this problem, clear your pod cache (pod cache clean) then do a fresh install to get the latest version!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I guess there is a problem with the gRPC-core and a link is missing..

when I am not mistaken, it is used from Firestore and I guess it is since the last update from gRPC-Core

i only have

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

---

developers posted following on Github:

Looks like an issue in gRPC-Core. For the time being you can work around this by putting

pod 'gRPC', `1.6.5`
at the top of your Podfile.

Comment: Just saw this is being tracked currently on the Firebase Github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/423 hopefully there is a fix soon.